# Do I qualify for a Dutch Passport if my mother was a Dutch National?

Tags: citizenship, passport, canadian-citizens, children, dutch-citizens

My mothers family has lived in the Netherlands since the year 1542. My grandparents (mothers parents) moved to Canada when my mother was 10 years old. My unmarried mother had me when she was 19 years old, so her Dutch National designation had not expired yet, from what I understand. She put me up for adoption and later I found my Dutch family. I have an adoption record stating my birth name. Do I qualify for a Dutch passport or other legal Dutch designation? Thank you for your kind attention to this matter. Marie Janisse

Comment: I would think that the adoption would complicate matters here, but IANAL, so that's why this is a comment and not an answer.  Ordinarily, I would presume you to be a Dutch citizen (if born after 1985, the opposite if you were born before), based on the presumed nationality of your unmarried mother (and unknown nationality of the father)

Comment: When were you born?  When were you adopted?  Do you have a birth certificate showing your birth mother's name?

Comment: @MatthewBarclay most Dutch citizens born after 1985 who have another nationality, have never lived in the Netherlands, and have never received a Dutch passport or certificate of nationality will have lost their Dutch nationality upon turning 28.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments and questions. :)  I was born in October 1961 and adopted in December 1961. I do not have a birth certificate showing my birth mothers name, but I do have an adoption certificate showing my birth name (first, and last name the same as my birth mothers name). My birth mother was a Dutch citizen.